# cli-progress not showing up on typescript nodejs 16

Tags: node.js, typescript, console.log

cli-progress not showing up on typescript nodejs 16. What am i doing wrong here?

code

```
import cliProgress from "cli-progress";    

export const UpdateTags = (games:any[]) => {
        const bar1 = new cliProgress.SingleBar({}, cliProgress.Presets.shades_classic);
        bar1.start(games.length, 0);
    
        games.forEach((game, idx) => {
            game.tag = "game " + idx;
            bar1.update(idx);
        });
    
        bar1.stop();
    };
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "cli-progress": "^3.11.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cli-progress": "^3.11.0",
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. Try the following:

```
import { SingleBar } from 'cli-progress'
```

Comment: Hi, while your answer may address the question, it's better to explain why this should work, adding citations and documentation. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this in 2023 (vanilla JS):

```
import * as cliProgress from 'cli-progress';

const bar1 = new cliProgress.SingleBar({}, cliProgress.Presets.shades_classic);
bar1.start(someArray.length,0);
let progress = 0;

for (let val in someArray){
  //some code here
  progress++
  bar1.update(progress);
}

bar1.stop();
```

What was not super clear for me is that `bar1.update()` accepts target value
(progress bar position) not the increment value